# Python script to read different message patterns

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to make a flexible python script that read and extract some weather variables from synop code.

Here is the code:

```
import re

def extract_data_12_utc(message):
    # pattern message

    pattern = r'(\d{5}),(\d{4}),(\d{2}),(\d{2}),(\d{2}),(\d{2}),AAXX (\d{5}) (\d{5}) (\d{5}) (\d{5}) (1\d{4}) (2\d{4}) (3\d{4})? (4\d{4}) (6\d{4})? (7\d{4})? (8\d{4})? (\{3}) (2\d{4}) (5\d{4}) (7\d{4})'


    matches = re.search(pattern, message)

    # Check if the match is successsful
    if matches:
        
        station = matches.group(1)
        year = matches.group(2)
        month = matches.group(3)
        day = matches.group(4)
        hour = matches.group(5)
        min = matches.group(6)

        # Extracting variables
        temp_air = float(matches.group(11)[2:]) / 10.0
        temp_dew = float(matches.group(12)[2:]) / 10.0
        pres_station = float(matches.group(13)[1:]) / 10.0 + 1000  
        pres_sealv = float(matches.group(14)[1:]) / 10.0 + 1000
        prec_6h = float(matches.group(15)[2:4]) if matches.group(15) else None
        wx = str(matches.group(16)[1:]) if matches.group(16) else None
        cld = str(matches.group(17)[1:]) if matches.group(17) else None
        temp_min = float(matches.group(19)[2:]) / 10.0 if matches.group(19) else None
        pres_chg = float(matches.group(20)[2:]) / 10.0 if matches.group(20) else None
        prec_24h = float(matches.group(21)[1:]) / 10.0 if matches.group(21) else None

        # Formatting results
        formatted_data = [
            station, year, month, day, hour, min,
            f"{int(temp_air):02d}.{int((temp_air % 1) * 10):01d}",
            f"{int(temp_dew):02d}.{int((temp_dew % 1) * 10):01d}",
            f"{int(pres_station):04d}.{int((pres_station % 1) * 10):01d}",
            f"{int(pres_sealv):04d}.{int((pres_sealv % 1) * 10):01d}",
            f"{int(prec_6h):1d}"  if prec_6h is not None else "None",
            f"{int(wx):1d}"  if wx is not None else "None",
            f"{int(cld):1d}"  if cld is not None else "None",
            f"{int(temp_min):02d}.{int((temp_min % 1) * 10):01d}",
            f"{int(pres_chg):1d}"  if pres_chg is not None else "None",
            f"{prec_24h:.1f}" if prec_24h is not None else "None"
        ]

        # Returns formatted data
        return formatted_data
    else:
        # Returns list if fails
        return ["None"] * 16

# Reading file
file_name = r"synop.txt"
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# List to store results
data_12_utc = []

# From 17th line
for line in lines:
    data = extract_data_12_utc(line)
    data_12_utc.append(data)

# Show formatted data
for data in data_12_utc:
    print(data)
```

The input data is:

```
82145,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82145 32598 30502 10292 20250 30082 40124 83200 333 20231 58004=
82181,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82181 21498 73603 10257 20242 30008 40149 70262 84520 333 20246 59014 60084=
82184,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82184 21498 60502 10272 20252 30116 40124 70362 85520 333 20243 59014 69944=
82188,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82188 11560 53602 10264 20248 30128 40146 60214 72162 83260 333 58002 70210==
82191,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82191 12570 60501 10290 20262 30108 40114 60184 84250 333 20238 59014 70180==
82193,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82193 22470 30409 10289 20254 30106 40124 83100 333 20254 59016 60054=
82244,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82244 11470 70503 10269 20248 30061 40130 60024 70296 84220 333 20256 59002 70020==
82246,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82246 21596 83202 10252 20242 3//// 4//// 7036/ 887// 333 2//// 5//// 60254=
82263,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82263 11470 8//// 30118 69934 70352 887// 333 59013 70003==
82353,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82353 22497 63602 10264 20246 30002 40086 86400 333 20215 59014 60024=
82361,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82361 21497 63602 10276 20258 30088 40125 70265 86700 333 20269 59018 60024=
82444,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82444 12470 72703 10269 20252 30091 60624 85000 333 20270 58000 70620==
82445,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82445 22497 83202 10266 20254 30102 40154 8472/ 333 20243 58000 60314=
82562,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82562 32597 836// 1//// 2//// 3//// 4//// 8869/ 333 2//// 5////=
82861,2024,01,24,12,00,AAXX 24124 82861 21596 73202 1//// 2//// 39917 4//// 70360 8572/ 333 2//// 59027 60054=
```

However, it returns like this:

```
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
```

When I limit some variables (i.e until group 15), it returns:

```
['82145', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '29.1', '25.0', '1008.2', '1012.3', 'None']
['82181', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '25.6', '24.1', '1000.7', '1014.8', 'None']
['82184', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '27.1', '25.1', '1011.6', '1012.3', 'None']
['82188', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '26.3', '24.8', '1012.7', '1014.6', '21']
['82191', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '29.0', '26.1', '1010.7', '1011.3', '18']
['82193', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '28.8', '25.3', '1010.6', '1012.3', 'None']
['82244', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '26.8', '24.8', '1006.1', '1013.0', '2']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['82353', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '26.3', '24.6', '1000.2', '1008.6', 'None']
['82361', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '27.6', '25.8', '1008.7', '1012.5', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['82445', '2024', '01', '24', '12', '00', '26.6', '25.3', '1010.2', '1015.3', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
```

How I would have a script that comprise all types of pattern messages?

Comment: what is expected output? Can you build an example correct output manually? Presently the full line is interpreted as 16 None even if one variable malformed.

Comment: what `/` or `=` stands for? Just a malformed variable? Why 333 is in each line?

Comment: /: stands for a missing value. = or == stand for end of message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a rationale in rejecting the whole line (or replacing with None strings) even if only one variable malformed.

However, if you like to extract every well-formed variable, even if some of variable in the line are malformed, you should split the line into variable list using, say, `re.split(', ', line)`, and convert/check each variable separately. Unfortunately, `re` matches the whole expression not each group

If you must to use one flexible regular expression it should account for potentially malformed groups with something like `(?:(4\d{4})|\d*[/]+)` .
Regretfully, it increases the number of groups, so I used non-capturing group operator `:?` to keep the group numbering the same. If you find it too unwieldy, another option is to use more universal groups expressions `(4[/\d]{4})`, that permit for missing value but latter you will have test presence of missing digit sign '/' or just catch exception during conversion.

Comment: Yes, I was trying somthing like ((4\d{4})| (6\d{4)?), but I'll try you suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem could be with the pattern you've used. Pattern can just fail to catch strings as they have not so many data included (look at the second output, some rows remain None whereas others are now fetched successfully). Try to make some of the groups as possible with the `?` sign and check for the None at the Python side if needed